# How to configure both ipv4 & ipv6 address

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

how to configure both ipv4 and ipv6 address through softlayer sdk java?

I executed below sample code to configure both ip versions, but its configured only ipv4. can you please help me to configure ipv6 address while submit the createObject request.

softlayer sdk java version: 0.2.3

```
    Image image = new Image();
    image.setCapacity(50L);

    Guest guest = new Guest();
    guest.setHostname("malya-vm-4");
    guest.setDomain("test.com");
    guest.setStartCpus(1l);
    guest.setMaxMemory(1024l);
    guest.setDatacenter(new Location());
    guest.getDatacenter().setName("che01");

    guest.setLocalDiskFlag(false);
    guest.setHourlyBillingFlag(true);

    guest.setOperatingSystemReferenceCode("UBUNTU_LATEST");

    Component privateComponent = new Component();
    Component publicComponent = new Component();

    Vlan networkVlan1 = new Vlan();
    networkVlan1.setVlanNumber(1365L);
    networkVlan1.setId(2117919L);

    Subnet privateSubnet = new Subnet();
    privateSubnet.setId(1059121L);

    privateComponent.setNetworkVlan(networkVlan1);
    privateComponent.setPrimarySubnet(privateSubnet);
    guest.setPrimaryBackendNetworkComponent(privateComponent);

    Vlan networkVlan2 = new Vlan();
    networkVlan2.setId(2117917L);
    networkVlan2.setVlanNumber(1290L);

    Subnet primarySubnetVersion4 = new Subnet();
    primarySubnetVersion4.setVersion(4L);
    primarySubnetVersion4.setId(1547547L);

    Subnet ipv6 = Subnet.service(client, 1512739L).getObject();
    Subnet primarySubnetVersion6 = new Subnet();
    primarySubnetVersion6.setVersion(6L);
    primarySubnetVersion6.setId(1512739L);
    primarySubnetVersion6.setSubnetType("PRIMARY_6");

     networkVlan2.setPrimarySubnet(primarySubnetVersion4);
    networkVlan2.setPrimarySubnetVersion6(ipv6);
    networkVlan2.setPrimarySubnetCount(2L);

    publicComponent.setNetworkVlan(networkVlan2);
    guest.setPrimaryNetworkComponent(publicComponent);
    Guest.service(client).createObject(guest);
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid you will not be able to configure the VSI with both ip versions, the [createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject) method is a simplified alternative to order VSIs, it means that some additional configurations cannot be set using this method. In fact, if you execute the method [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getCreateObjectOptions](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getCreateObjectOptions) you will not be able to see any option for ipv6.

I recommend to use [placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method if you want to order VSI with ip address v6. Following is an example, don’t forget change values like username, apiKey, location, and prices with your own data.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.Receipt;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.Vlan;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.Order;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.item.Price;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.guest.network.Component;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class orderVSI {

    public orderVSI(){
        // Declare username and api key
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Declare required variables to place an order
        long quantity = 1;
        String location = "MEXICO";
        long packageId = 46;

        // Declare Vlans you want to use
        Vlan publicVlan = new Vlan();
        publicVlan.setId(1133383L);

        Vlan privateVlan = new Vlan();
        privateVlan.setId(1133381L);

        // Vlans need to be into network components
        Component primaryNetworkComponent = new Component();
        primaryNetworkComponent.setNetworkVlan(publicVlan);

        Component backendNetworkComponent = new Component();
        backendNetworkComponent.setNetworkVlan(privateVlan);

        // Declare hostname, domain and network components of guests you want to order, add more guest objects if
        // quantity is greater than 1
        List<Guest> virtualGuests = new ArrayList<Guest>();
        Guest guest1 = new Guest();
        guest1.setHostname("hostname-test");
        guest1.setDomain("sl-domain.com");

        guest1.setPrimaryNetworkComponent(primaryNetworkComponent);
        guest1.setPrimaryBackendNetworkComponent(backendNetworkComponent);

        virtualGuests.add(guest1);

        // Declare the list of prices. To get list of all available prices you can use the method
        // SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices
        long[] pricesIds = {
                52283,    // 1 x 2.0 GHz Cores
                51209,    // 1 GB RAM
                45466,    // CentOS 7.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)
                2202,     // "25 GB (SAN) as First disk
                1800,     // 0 GB Bandwidth
                17129,    // Primary IPv6 Addresses
                273,      // 100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks
                55,       // Monitoring - Host Ping
                57,       // Email and Ticket
                58,       // Automated Notification
                21,       // Primary IP Addresses
                418,      // Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reportin
                420,      // VPN Management - Private Network
                905       // Remote Management
        };

        // Building the skeleton of SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price objects
        List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<Price>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pricesIds.length; i++) {
            Price p = new Price();
            p.setId(pricesIds[i]);
            prices.add(p);
        }

        // Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order object template that will be used to order VSIs.
        com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order orderTemplate = new com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order();
        orderTemplate.setLocation(location);
        orderTemplate.setPackageId(packageId);
        orderTemplate.setQuantity(quantity);
        orderTemplate.getVirtualGuests().addAll(virtualGuests);
        orderTemplate.getPrices().addAll(prices);

        // Get Api Client and service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Order.Service orderService = Order.service(client);

        try{
            // verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with placeOrder() when
            // you're ready to order.
            Receipt receipt = orderService.placeOrder(orderTemplate, Boolean.FALSE);
            // com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order receipt = orderService.verifyOrder(orderTemplate);

            // Print response in JSON format
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(receipt));

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new orderVSI();
    }
}
```

Comment: is not possible to configure the IPV6 address with Guest Service object? Just we are referring a sample code from softlayer documentation.

Comment: The only way is through placeOrder method. I improved the java code in order to set hostname, domain and vlans. The example should create a VSI with ipv4 and ipv6 using specific vlans.

Comment: Am getting the below error message while executing the above suggested code,  Error: com.softlayer.api.ApiException$Internal: Invalid data on the order for property: virtualGuests. Hostname and domain are not set properly.(code: SoftLayer_Exception_Order_InvalidData, status: 500) .is not possible to configure the IPV6 address with Guest Service object? Just we are referring a sample code from softlayer documentation.

Comment: I updated the code and I was able to order a VSI, I tested it on java api version 0.2.4.